# Powershell / Multiple Checkboxes, one event handler

Tags: powershell, user-interface, exchangewebservices

I am making a PowerShell script that creates a graphical user interface (GUI) application using Windows Forms, and allows the user to select specific mailbox properties via Check Boxes (e.g., DisplayName, UserPrincipalName) to export to a CSV file for a list of mailboxes.

There are a ton of mailbox (Exchange) properties. Such as DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, Alias etc. This program will pretty much save a few minutes of time by avoid editing a exported CSV from Office 365. It is most likely I have spent more time on this than I would just editing a exported CSV for the rest of my career :P

In short, multiple check boxes with unique properties and a singular event handler.

I am currently creating a individual checkbox and a individual event handler for each individual checkbox. For example, imagine the below repeated 30+ times for different mailbox properties:

```
#Creates a new Check Box named $DisplayNameCheckBox
$DisplayNameCheckBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
#Displays the text "DisplayName" next to the check box
$DisplayNameCheckBox.Text = "DisplayName"
#Places the $ExitButton on the GUI at (X,Y) position
$DisplayNameCheckBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 20)
#Adds a click event handler to the button. The code inside the script block { ... } will execute when the button is clicked.
$DisplayNameCheckBox.Add_Click({
        #If $DisplayNameCheckBox is ticked (true)
            if ($DisplayNameCheckBox.Checked) {
                #"DisplayNameCheckBox is checked" is displayed in console
                Write-Host "DisplayNameCheckBox is checked"
                #Adds DisplayName to ArrayList
                $mailboxPropertiesArrayList.Add("DisplayName")
                #"Current Values in mailboxPropertiesArrayList: $mailboxPropertiesArrayList" is displayed in console
                Write-Host "Current Values in mailboxPropertiesArrayList: $mailboxPropertiesArrayList"
```

I have created a function that essentially creates these check boxes and reduces the lines of code needed compared to individually creating them. There is now one Event Handler that handles all of these check boxes. However, I have encountered some problems:

- The mailbox $property of the checkbox is valued as 'Null'. It appears the the $checkBox.Add_Click does not know what checkbox is being clicked
  This might be because the  $checkBox.Add_Click was within in the function. I tried returning this but I expected some weird behaviour where it was either null or the value of $property was the incorrect value.

I need a way to reduce the amount of code when creating these checkboxes but I also need the program to identify which checkbox is being clicked so it can accurately be added to mailboxPropertiesArrayList (I made mailboxPropertiesArrayList Global when debugging and not changed it back yet. Please ignore :) )

I have created a function that essentially creates these check boxes and reduces the lines of code used. For example:

```
function Add-CheckBox($text, $location, $propertyName) {
        Write-Host $propertyName
        $checkBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
        $checkBox.Text = $text
        $checkBox.Location = $location
        $FormGUI.Controls.Add($checkBox)
        $property = $propertyName
    
        # Return the checkbox and property name as an object
        return [PSCustomObject]@{
            CheckBox = $checkBox
            PropertyName = $property
    }
}
```

```
# Define checkbox properties and add them to the form
$checkboxes = @()
$checkboxes += Add-CheckBox "DisplayName" (New-Object Drawing.Point(10, 20)) "DisplayName"
$checkboxes += Add-CheckBox "UserPrincipalName" (New-Object Drawing.Point(10, 42)) "UserPrincipalName"
$checkboxes += Add-CheckBox "Alias" (New-Object Drawing.Point(10, 60)) "Alias"
$checkboxes += Add-CheckBox "TotalItemSize" (New-Object Drawing.Point(10, 80)) "TotalItemSize"
```

The Event Click Handler was originally within the function. The value of $property is null.

It appears the the $checkBox.Add_Click does not know what checkbox is being clicked. It has no idea. This might be because the  $checkBox.Add_Click is in a function. This was my previous attempt: - I also had mailboxPropertiesArrayList as a global variable in case this was also being lost within the function.

```
# Function to create and add a checkbox to the form
function Add-CheckBox($text, $location, $propertyName) {
    Write-Host $propertyName
    $checkBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    $checkBox.Text = $text
    $checkBox.Location = $location
    $FormGUI.Controls.Add($checkBox)
    
    # Define the click event handler for the checkbox
    $checkBox.Add_Click({
        param($sender, $eventArgs)
        $clickedCheckBox = $sender
        $property = $propertyName  # Capture the value of $propertyName in the closure
        if ($clickedCheckBox.Checked) {
            Write-Host "$property CheckBox is checked"
            $Global:mailboxPropertiesArrayList.Add($property)
            Write-Host "Current Values in mailboxPropertiesArrayList: $($Global:mailboxPropertiesArrayList -join ', ')"
        }
    })
}
```

I then had all the check boxes created in the function to reduce the lines of code to make each check box and then $checkBox.Add_Click was placed outside the function. For example:

```
foreach ($checkbox in $checkboxes) {
    $checkbox.CheckBox.Add_Click({
        param($sender, $eventArgs)
        $clickedCheckBox = $sender
        $property = $checkbox.PropertyName  # Use the PropertyName from the checkbox object
        if ($clickedCheckBox.Checked) {
            Write-Host "$property CheckBox is checked"
            $Global:mailboxPropertiesArrayList.Add($property)
            Write-Host "Current Values in mailboxPropertiesArrayList: $($Global:mailboxPropertiesArrayList -join ', ')"
        }
    })
}
```

I was getting closer. Now $property has a value but the value is always TotalItemSize no matter which check box I click.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

`$sender.Text` is how you identify what specific checkbox is clicked:

```
foreach ($checkbox in $checkboxes) {
    $checkbox.CheckBox.Add_Click({
        param($sender, $eventArgs)
        if ($sender.Checked) {
            Write-Host "$($sender.Text) CheckBox is checked"
            $Global:mailboxPropertiesArrayList.Add($sender.Text)
            Write-Host "Current Values in mailboxPropertiesArrayList: $($Global:mailboxPropertiesArrayList -join ', ')"
        }
    })
}
```